# Always get authentication failure when use svn with netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, authentication

I am trying Netbeans subversion features, I found when I try to commit to my googlecode subversion repository, I always get authentication failure.

I am 100% sure didn't input the wrong username or password, and I have tested this on another computer and everything works just fine.

What might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Eclipse, when I installed the eclipse subversion plugin using SVNKit Client I negelcted to install the SVNKit Library - I could check out code from my repos, but could not check it back in.

After looking at everything else I finally installed the SVNKit lib and problem solved.

Hope this helps